# sql - Select one column with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables and I want a result: if CID and CID2 are equal print cpu about value of CID2

```
first table A :
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| CID  | time                | step               | time_in_seconde |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|    1 | 2017-07-27 06:26:50 | gege               |          10.229 |
|    2 | 2017-07-27 06:26:58 | rere               |          10.239 |
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 | gege               |          13.229 |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 | titi               |          12.823 |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 | fefe               |          12.667 |



second table B  :
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
| CID2 | time                | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |          0.01   |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 |          0.05   |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 |          0.03   |
```

result :

```
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
| CID2 | time                | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    1 | 2017-07-27 06:26:50 |                 |
|    2 | 2017-07-27 06:26:58 |                 |
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |          0.01   |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 |          0.05   |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 |          0.03   |
```

my sql request don't work :

```
select A.cid, A.time, C.cpu from A INNER JOIN B on A.cid = B.CID2 where A.time ="2018-12-17 14:00:00";
```

i use mariadb and i need with condition time = 2017-07-27 06:55:04, because i have millions line

do you have any idea, thanks for any information

Comment: Hint : `LEFT JOIN` with `tableB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that with a left join, something like

```
select 
  ta.CID, ta.time,tb.cpu 
from 
  TableA ta 
left join 
  TableB tb on ta.CID=tb.CID2
```

if you want to avoid `cpu` is null, convert it to some other value, e.g. 0 with `ISNULL(cpu,0)`

Take a look at the different join types on w3schools here : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: i have this : +------+---------------------+-----------------+
| CID2 | time                | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    1 | 2017-07-27 06:26:50 |       0.01      |
|    2 | 2017-07-27 06:26:58 |       0.05      |
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |       0.03      |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 |                 |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 |                 |           see below what i want

Comment: Sorry, but  I'm unable to decipher what you mean in your comment :)

Comment: Im just more confused now, how can the row with  timestamp 2017-07-27 06:26:50 suddenly have a cpu time?? And did you even try my answer, or a variation of it ?

Comment: with you query i have  1 | 2017-07-27 06:26:50 |       0.01      , i want 3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |          0.01    because in table B i have |    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |          0.01   |

Comment: Could you show exactly what query you are using to get that result?

Comment: yes, select A.CID, A.time, B.cpu from A left outer join B on A.CID = B.CID2 where A.time ="2018-12-17 14:00:00" group by A.CID;

Comment: Hmm, your where clause ensures you only get rows with that timestamp, and why the group by (and how can you even get columns out that is not included in the group by columns or an aggregate - is that something mariadb specific

Comment: I dont think i can help you any further, your question isn't precise enough - i suggest you dive into the different join types as described by w3schools or others. Best of luck

Comment: can you please with the condition time 2017-07-27 06:26:58 , because i have my rows

Answer (score 0):

You need a query with left join like below:

```
select t1.CID, t1.time, t2.CPU
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t2.CID2 = t1.CID
```

Comment: Qualify time column as well.

Comment: i don't want as you wrote, see below please @Eray Balkanli

Comment: @dfgert it is not clear what you want. How come CPU:0.01 is for ID:1 in your resultset while it is actually for ID:3, how do we decide this change?

Comment: @dfgert you sql uses "inner join", please try "left join"

Comment: @Eray Balkanli  can you please with the condition time 2017-07-27 06:26:58 , because i have my rows